# Angular 'View Child' only working with template reference variable and not with class name

Tags: angular, viewchild

I created a simple paginator component that I use all over my app. I am using view child to access some of the properties; however I encountered a weird bug with View Child.

When I use the component class name (PaginatorComponent) as the selector for view child, it is undefined. However, when I switch to a template reference variable everything works as expected.  The bug only shows up in the deployed version of my app: everything worked fine locally (even in production mode) and I haven't been able to replicate it in a Stackblitz.

I am using Angular and Angular Material, and the deployed app is running with other micro-frontends using single-spa/angular.

I have searched and searched but can find nothing helpful. Does anyone know of a nuance in Angular / View Child that would cause this issue? I am able to get around the issue by using template reference variables, but it bothers me that I cannot figure out why using the class name doesn't work.

Paginator ts

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, Input, OnInit, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { paginationConfigs } from 'configs';

export interface PageChangeEvent {
  pageNumber: string;
  pageLength: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-paginator',
  templateUrl: './paginator.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./paginator.component.css'],
})
export class PaginatorComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() viewingLastPage: boolean;

  public _pageIndex = 0;
  get pageIndex(): number {
    return this._pageIndex;
  }
  set pageIndex(val: number) {
    this._pageIndex = val;
    this.pageNumberChange.emit({
      pageLength: this.pageLength,
      pageNumber: val.toString(),
    });
  }

  public _pageLength = paginationConfigs.pageLengthOptions[0];
  get pageLength(): string {
    return this._pageLength;
  }
  set pageLength(val) {
    this._pageLength = val;
    this.pageLengthChange.emit({
      pageLength: val,
      pageNumber: this.pageIndex.toString(),
    });
  }
  public pageLengthOptions: string[] = paginationConfigs.pageLengthOptions;
  @Output() pageNumberChange: EventEmitter<PageChangeEvent> = new EventEmitter<
    PageChangeEvent
  >();
  @Output() pageLengthChange: EventEmitter<PageChangeEvent> = new EventEmitter<
    PageChangeEvent
  >();
  @Output() initialized: EventEmitter<PageChangeEvent> = new EventEmitter<PageChangeEvent>();

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.emitInitialized();
  }

  changePage(change: number): void {
    this.pageIndex += change;
  }

  emitPageNumberChange(): void {
    this.pageNumberChange.emit({
      pageNumber: this.pageIndex.toString(),
      pageLength: this.pageLength,
    });
  }

  emitInitialized(): void {
    this.initialized.emit({
      pageNumber: this.pageIndex.toString(),
      pageLength: this.pageLength
    });
  }
}
```

paginator html

```
<div class="paginator">
    <mat-form-field class="length-dropdown">
        <mat-label>Page Length</mat-label>
        <mat-select [(value)]="this.pageLength">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let length of pageLengthOptions" [value]="length">{{length}}</mat-option>
        </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
    <button mat-icon-button class="previous-page-navigate" (click)="changePage(-1)" [disabled]="this.pageIndex === 0">
        <mat-icon>keyboard_arrow_left</mat-icon>
      </button>
      <span>{{ this.pageIndex + 1 }} </span>
      <button mat-icon-button class="next-page-navigate" (click)="changePage(+1)" [disabled]="viewingLastPage">
        <mat-icon>keyboard_arrow_right</mat-icon>
      </button>
</div>
```

parent ts

```
export class WebsiteConfigComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild(WebsiteListTableComponent) table: WebsiteListTableComponent;
  @ViewChild(PaginatorComponent) paginator: PaginatorComponent;

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.loadWebsites();
  }

  loadWebsites() {
    this.getWebsiteList(this.paginator.pageLength, this.paginator.pageIndex.toString());
  }
...
```

parent html

```
    <div class="website-filters">
  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Website</mat-label>
    <input matInput [(ngModel)]="searchString" autocomplete="off" />
  </mat-form-field>
  <button mat-raised-button (click)="searchWebsites()">Search</button>
  <button mat-raised-button (click)="resetFilters()">Reset</button>
  <button mat-raised-button (click)="createNewWebsite()">
    Create New Website
  </button>
  <button mat-raised-button routerLink="/app/configurations">Back</button>
</div>
<div class="websites-table">
  <app-website-list-table
    [websites]="websites"
    (viewWebsite)="editWebsite($event)"
    [ngClass]="{'table-loading': this.loading$ | async}"
  ></app-website-list-table>
</div>
<div class="spinner" *ngIf="this.loading$ | async">
  <mat-spinner></mat-spinner>
</div>
<app-paginator #paginator [viewingLastPage]="endOfList" (pageNumberChange)="onPageNumberChange($event)"></app-paginator>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please paste your parent ts code for using `paginator` part, since there is one thing to consider is `AfterViewInit`, you need to wait for the view to be initialized before you can access your `@ViewChild`.

Comment: Added the code but I know that is not the problem.

Comment: I can't reproduce you mentioned issue, so maybe you can try below two method:1. Try to use settimeout to wrapper method 'this.loadWebsites();' 2. Use @ViewChildren and then subscribe the changes in ngAfterViewInit;

Comment: I've tried that already, but thanks for trying to help.